# Trying to add child to div class

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to add a canvas child to my div with the bb-item class.

this is my current code.

```js
var createImage = function(w, h) {
  var i = document.createElement("canvas");
  i.width = w;
  i.height = h;
  i.ctx = i.getContext("2d");
  return i;
}
var canvas = createImage(1024, 512);
var ctx = canvas.ctx;
document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item').appendChild(canvas);
```

```html
<div class="bb-item cover">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: What issue or error are you getting with this code?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Could you please provide more details? Such as what error you are getting and possible a HTML snippet of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: I have a javascript code for moving footprints, im trying to place this script under the div class bb-item. Currently my script doesnt run in the <canvas> under the bb-item. This code worked when i had 

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

The problem here is that the canvas is placed in the body element which is not what i want.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('bb-item')` is HTMLCollection array. You need to pass the array index. `document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item')[0].appendChild(canvas);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you are using [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), it returns a **collection** of DOM nodes (even if only a single element matches the selector):

> Returns an **array-like object** of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

That means that you either have to

- select the first element in the collection, if you are sure you only want to work with the **very first element in the collection**, i.e.:

  ```
  document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item')[0].appendChild(canvas);
  ```
- Or, if you want to apply the same method to **all elements in the collection**, then iterate through the collection before applying the `.appendChild()` method:

  ```
  var bbItems = document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item');

  for (var i = 0; i < bbItems.length; i++) {
    var bbItem = bbItems[i];
    bbItem.appendChild(canvas);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this statement:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item').appendChild(canvas);
```

with this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item')[0].appendChild(canvas);
```

```js
var createImage = function(w, h) {
  var i = document.createElement("canvas");
  i.width = w;
  i.height = h;
  i.ctx = i.getContext("2d");
  return i;
}
var canvas = createImage(1024, 512);
var ctx = canvas.ctx;
document.getElementsByClassName('bb-item')[0].appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
.bb-item{
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

canvas{
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bb-item cover">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```